# lower and upper quartiles in boxplot in R

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I have

```
X = c(20 ,18, 34, 45, 30, 51, 63, 52, 29, 36, 27, 24)
```

With `boxplot`, i'm trying to plot the `quantile(X,0.25)` and `quantile(X,0.75)`
but this is not realy the same lower and upper quartiles in boxplot in R

```
boxplot(X)
abline(h=quantile(X,0.25), col="red", lty=2)
abline(h=quantile(X,0.75), col="red", lty=2)
```

[image]
Do you know why?

Comment: btw, `boxplot` returns an object that can be used as needed: `bX = boxplot(X); abline(h = bX$stats[c(2, 4), 1], col = "red",lty = 2)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The values of the box are called hinges and may coincide with the quartiles (as calculated by `quantile(x, c(0.25, .075))`), but are calculated differently.

From `?boxplot.stats`:

> The two ‘hinges’ are versions of the first and third quartile, i.e., close to quantile(x, c(1,3)/4). The hinges equal the quartiles for odd n (where n <- length(x)) and differ for even n. Whereas the quartiles only equal observations for n %% 4 == 1 (n = 1 mod 4), the hinges do so additionally for n %% 4 == 2 (n = 2 mod 4), and are in the middle of two observations otherwise.

To see that the values coincide with an odd number of observations, try the following code:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(9)

boxplot(x)
abline(h=quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.75)), col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The discrepancy arises from an ambiguity in the definition of quantiles. No single method is strictly correct or incorrect - there are simply different ways to estimate quantiles in situations (such as an an even number of data points) when they do not neatly coincide with a specific data point and must be interpolated. Somewhat disconcertingly, `boxplot` and `quantile` (and other functions that provide summary statistics) use different default methods to calculate quantiles, although these defaults can be over-ridden using the `type =`  argument in `quantile`

We can see these differences more clearly in action by looking at some of the various ways to generate quantile statistics in R.

Both `boxplot` and `fivenum` give the same values:

```
boxplot.stats(X)$stats
# [1] 18.0 25.5 32.0 48.0 63.0
fivenum(X)
# [1] 18.0 25.5 32.0 48.0 63.0
```

In `boxplot` and `fivenum`, the lower (upper) quartile is equivalent to the median of the lower (upper) half of the data (including the median of the complete data):

```
c(median(X[ X <= median(X) ]), median(X[ X >= median(X) ]))
# [1] 25.5  48.0
```

But, `quartile` and `summary` do things differently:

```
summary(X)
#  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# 18.00   26.25   32.00   35.75   46.50   63.00

quantile(X, c(0.25,0.5,0.75))
#   25%   50%   75% 
# 26.25 32.00 46.50
```

The difference between this and the results from `boxplot` and `fivenum`  hinges on how the functions interpolate between data. `quartile` attempts to interpolate by estimating the shape of the cumulative distribution function.  According to `?quantile`:

> quantile returns estimates of underlying distribution quantiles based
> on one or two order statistics from the supplied elements in x at
> probabilities in probs. One of the nine quantile algorithms discussed
> in Hyndman and Fan (1996), selected by type, is employed.

The full details of the nine different methods `quantile` employs to estimate the distribution function of the data can be found in `?quantile`, and are too lengthy to reproduce in full here. The important point to note is that the 9 methods are taken from Hyndman and Fan (1996) who recommended type 8. The default method used by `quantile` is type 7, for historical reasons of compatibility with S.
We can see the estimates of the quartiles provided by different methods in quantile using:

```
quantile_methods = data.frame(
           q25 = sapply(1:9, function(method) quantile(X, 0.25, type = method)),
           q50 = sapply(1:9, function(method) quantile(X, 0.50, type = method)),
           q75 = sapply(1:9, function(method) quantile(X, 0.75, type = method)))

#       q25 q50    q75
# 1 24.0000  30 45.000
# 2 25.5000  32 48.000
# 3 24.0000  30 45.000
# 4 24.0000  30 45.000
# 5 25.5000  32 48.000
# 6 24.7500  32 49.500
# 7 26.2500  32 46.500
# 8 25.2500  32 48.500
# 9 25.3125  32 48.375
```

In which `type = 5` provides the same estimated values of the quartiles as does `boxplot`. However, when there are an odd number of data, it is `type=7` that will coincide with boxplot stats.

We can show this works by automatically selecting the type to be either 5 or 7 depending on whether there are an odd or even number of data. Boxplot in image below show quantiles for data sets with 1 to 30 values, with `boxplot` and `quantile` giving the same values for both odd and even N:

```
layout(matrix(1:30,5,6, byrow = T), respect = T)
par(mar=c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2), bty="n", yaxt="n", xaxt="n")

for (N in 1:30){
  X = sample(100, N)
  boxplot(X)
  abline(h=quantile(X, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), type=c(5,7)[(N %% 2) + 1]), col="red", lty=2)
}
```

[image]

---

Hyndman, R. J. and Fan, Y. (1996) Sample quantiles in statistical packages, American Statistician 50, 361–365

Answer (score 4):

One can specify the method for calculating the sample quantile using the `type =` argument in `quantile`, but not in `boxplot`. However, there is an R package on CRAN, [`qboxplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qboxplot/index.html), that contains a function also called `qboxplot` (hence `qboxplot::qboxplot`) that allows one to specify the quantile calculation method using the `qtype =` argument.

Comment: This was very helpful for me - thanks. I was going to have to go back and do "fixes" amongst a huge number of variables so the summary statistics and box-plots matched, so this was a savior.