# Inconsistent Whiskers upper distance with 1.5 IQR

Tags: r, boxplot, iqr

Same data, using two different boxplot methods provide two different length for the Whiskers, I understand that the whisker only goes as far as the maximum (minimum) point less (greater) than the upper (lower) fence value. In my case they are picking a different maximum point or the fence is miscalculated. From what I read in the documentation both methods are using 1.5 IRQ and the fence limit should be 57.8 so 39 should be chosen not 58.8

http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_boxplot.html

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/boxplot.stats.html

`geom_boxplot`

[image: geom_boxplot]
vs boxplot
[image: boxplot]

```
df=data.frame(num=c(81.16469 ,11.59219 ,29.7309 ,86.03547 ,16.42667 ,33.52099 ,26.07814 ,30.91522 ,39.49079 ,31.634 ,37.8732 ,20.50268 ,16.9127 ,20.1115 ,23.74309 ,22.30444 ,24.21399 ,27.30867 ,39.07071 ,14.81049 ,21.42116 ,23.30437 ,17.94871 ,17.50281 ,58.82008 ,20.18478 ,10.65572 ,37.97092 ,25.16336 ,35.69668))
quantile(df$num)
      0%      25%      50%      75%     100% 
10.65572 20.12982 24.68867 35.15276 86.03547 
boxplot(df$num)
IQR(df$num)*1.5+quantile(df$num)[4]
     75% 
57.68716 
ggplot(df,aes("x",num))+geom_boxplot()
boxplot(df$num)
```

And more importantly I want to extract from `df$num` the stats (vector of length 5, containing the extreme of the lower whisker, the lower ‘hinge’, the median, the upper ‘hinge’ and the extreme of the upper whisker) using any function, so   I can add text to `ggplot` in specific locations. `boxplot.stats(df$num)$stats` below provides those stats but the upper whisker is not matching my `ggplot` results.

```
boxplot.stats(df$num)$stats
[1] 10.65572 20.11150 24.68867 35.69668 58.82008
```

Comment: The 25th and 75th quantiles are often not equivalent to the hinges. You can use `fivenum` to calculate the hinges. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634693/lower-and-upper-quartiles-in-boxplot-in-r/40634859#40634859) might also be helpful.

Comment: I see how that can affect the IQR calculation and in turn the fence limit, that's a possible explanation of the issue. However, in practical terms I sill would like to find a way to get the values of the upper whisker to match my `ggplot`, the 39.4 or something for my example.