# Boxplot in R function

Tags: r

I have this function that computes outliers of an IQR and need to add a boxplot as a side-effect. I have this so far, and it works, but it also prints out a bunch of information about the boxplot, which I don't want.

```
IQR.outliers <- function(x) {
  if(any(is.na(x)))
    stop("x is missing values")
  if(!is.numeric(x))
    stop("x is not numeric")
  Q3<-quantile(x,0.75)
  Q1<-quantile(x,0.25)
  IQR<-(Q3-Q1)
  left<-(Q1-(1.5*IQR))
  right<-(Q3+(1.5*IQR))
  list(IQR=IQR,left=x[x<left],right=x[x>right],boxplot(x))
}
```

Comment: there is also a function `IQR` for the iqr and `boxplot` computes the left and right outliers. just remove `boxplot(x)` from the `list(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. Firstly, as @rawr pointed out, you should not put the `boxplot` statement in your list if you don't want to return its values.  Moreover, if you want to use `boxplot` for its side effect of drawing the plot, then you should ensure that the statistics you return are the same as those in the plot.  Both your method for calculating the IQR and your method for calculating the outliers are incompatible with the way the plot is drawn:

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40639848/2761575) for a detailed explanantion of the difference between what `quantile` and `boxplot` will calculate.  Based on this difference, not only will the IQR on your plot be different from the result returned, but the outliers could also be different, because they are calculated based on the IQR.

So, what I would recommend is to use the function boxplot to both draw the plot and to calculate the satistics you want. Like this:

```
IQR.outliers <- function(x) {
  y = boxplot(x)
  list( IQR = diff(y$stats[c(2,4)]), 
        left = y$out[y$out < y$stats[1]],
        right = y$out[y$out > y$stats[5]])
}
```