# Change the quantile calculation method used in plotly

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly, r-plotly

I try to understand how to deal with the ggplotly quantile calcultion method.

```
    vec <- c(9.56630105983885, 9.2478753964443, 10.0860135756819, 8.61391863126551, 
    9.94710349615399, 7.14660035433632, 8.22017617694062, 10.0666294326466, 
    9.35484039252854, 12.5410005237513, 12.5687999720704, 9.91564647202826, 
    7.55332442693865, 11.2588496810078, 10.9914482049276, 11.9021198944421, 
    6.3190685543082, 9.22657465466812, 11.216871586139, 12.2549168985367
    )
library(tidyverse)
quantile( vec, c(1, 2.5, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 95, 97.5, 99)/100, na.rm = TRUE ) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    mutate_if( is.numeric, round, 3)
```

This is the quantile i can calculate

```
     1%  2.5%    5%   10%   25%   50%    75%    90%    95%  97.5%    99%
1 6.476 6.712 7.105 7.513 9.073 9.931 11.227 12.284 12.542 12.556 12.564
```

`geom_boxplot` have the same result

```
p <-data.frame(x=vec) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(1,x)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        coord_flip() +
        xlab( "" ) +
        theme( axis.text.y = element_blank() )
ggplot_build(p)$data
```

[image]

the lower is `9.073`

But `plotly` dont use the same method :

```
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

the lower is now `8.92`

I need to have consistent results betwwen the ggplotly output and the quantile table.
How can I change the calculation method used by plotly ?

Comment: Change the type in `quantile`? ;)

Comment: Here you can understand how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634693/lower-and-upper-quartiles-in-boxplot-in-r