# Why do the quartiles in summary differ to those calculated manually?

Tags: r

Why do I get a different value when calculating the quartiles for my data set in R?

These values are different

```
x <- c(66,72,79,84,102,110,123,144,162,169,414)
lowerQ <- median(c(66,72,79,84,102)) ; lowerQ
upperQ <- median(c(123,144,162,169,414)) ; upperQ
```

to these values

```
quantile(x)
summary(x)
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation in `?quantile` outlining the 9 (!) different options for calculation methods?

Comment: For instance, [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/134229) might be informative.

Comment: Ah @joran you beat me to it, shall I delete my answer?

Comment: @HectorHaffenden Not at all...I was actually looking for a duplicate, but found that crossvalidated post first, which seems pretty authoritative.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40639848/2761575

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply different ways to calculate quantiles (when you have Continuous vs Discontinuous data), 
see

```
?quantile
```

and look for the types arguments

```
x <- c(66,72,79,84,102,110,123,144,162,169,414)
lowerQ <- median(c(66,72,79,84,102)) ; lowerQ
upperQ <- median(c(123,144,162,169,414)) ; upperQ

quantile(x, type = 1)
66   79  110  162  414
```

From @joran comments, see [Deeper Explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134229/finding-quartiles-in-r)