# Calculating the five number summary in R results in incorrect values?

Tags: r, statistics

Using the latest version of R on a Windows 10 machine, I attempted to calculate the five number summary for the following dataset:

```
a <- c(175, 199, 204, 234, 259, 275, 299, 304, 317, 345, 355, 384, 549)
fivenum(a)

# Output
[1] 175 234 299 345 549
```

My answer was marked as incorrect since the correct answer is apparently:

```
175 219 299 350 549
```

If someone could explain what the issue is, I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose it depends on which formula is used for the quantiles e.g. R has a few ways `sapply(1:9, function(o) quantile(a, c(0.25, 0.75), type=o))`. Type 6 returns the values that you expect. The help page for `boxplot.stats` gives some info on the choices made for the statistics

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40639848/2761575

Comment: See the help! R uses Tukey's original definition of the 5 number summary in `fivenum` and `boxplot.stats` (where the 2nd and 4th values are the lower and upper *hinges* `?boxplot.stats` has details). No doubt you have been taught some variation on the original and will be expected to adhere to whatever definitions you have been given.