# I got slightly different qq plots in R and Python for the same data. Which one should I rely on?

Tags: python, r, stat

This is my data:

```
x = c(2.42, 2.59, 3.5, 2.75, 2.78, 3.58, 2.95, 2.06, 2.36, 2.48, 3.33, 2.89)
```

I got this qq plot from R:

```
qqnorm(x)
qqline(x)
```

[image]

Meanwhile, for the same data, I got the following qq plots with different settings from Python:

```
import pandas as pd

x = [2.42, 2.59, 3.5, 2.75, 2.78, 3.58, 2.95, 2.06, 2.36, 2.48, 3.33, 2.89]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['x'])

import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sm.qqplot(df['x'], line='s')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
sm.qqplot(df['x'], line='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
sm.qqplot(df['x'], line='q')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can see that the qq lines are all slightly different. Which qq plot/qq line should I rely on? Look forward to any information. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide complete Python code? I think you are importing pyplot from matplotlib, and is `data_GPA` a pandas dataframe?

Comment: There are several ways to calculate quantiles (you can specify which using the `qtype` argument in `qqnorm`).  Each will give slightly different results, (especially on small datasets like this).  see `?quantile` in R for lots more info, and have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40639848/2761575

Comment: Further to previous comment, if you are looking for advice on which quantile method to use for your specifc application, then that is a stats question not a programming one.  In that case, the question should be migrated to cross validated.

Comment: @dww By the way, I have removed the tag r but kept the tag Python and stat for this question. Probably I'm more interested in knowing how to generate exactly the same qqplot/qqline of R in Python. Do you know that? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** If you want R and Python to match, use `a = 1/2` to adjust the x-axis offset slightly in your Python plots.

All of these plots are only slightly different. Do any of them lead you to different qualitative conclusions about what's going on with your data??

The closest thing to R's `qqnorm()`/`qqline()` is `line = "q"`:

> ‘qqline’ adds a
> line to a “theoretical”, by default normal, quantile-quantile plot
> which passes through the ‘probs’ quantiles, by default the first
> and third quartiles.

After quite a bit of digging I discovered that the quantile definitions used here by Python and R **do** match (`qqline()` uses `type = 7` by default, which matches the definition of `scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile`, which is [used internally by Python's qqplot](https://www.statsmodels.org/0.9.0/_modules/statsmodels/graphics/gofplots.html#qqplot)). What differs is *the location of the x-axis plotting points*: Python uses an internal function defined as

```
(np.arange(1.,nobs+1) - a)/(nobs- 2*a + 1)
```

with an offset parameter `a` set to 0 by default, where R uses the `ppoints()` function, which is defined similarly but with a different default `a` value: `if(n <= 10) 3/8 else 1/2)` (see `?ppoints`).  Thus, you can get Python to match R's default if you use

```
sm.qqplot(x, line='q', a = 1/2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that we can answer the question "which one should I rely on?" A better question might be "can we make the Python output comparable or consistent with the R output?" And the answer to that seems to be "not really".

`qqline` takes an argument, `qtype =`  which determines how quantiles are calculated. You can read about it in the help page, `?qqline` There are 9 different methods. So we could add lines for all 9 methods like this:

```
sapply(1:9, function(q) qqline(x, qtype = q))
```

Using your data, we see this:

[image]

Now: the Python function `qqplot` [has four options](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html) to add a line: '45', 's', 'r' and 'q'.

We might think that 'q' (fit through quartiles) would match one of the 9 methods from R `qqline`. But it appears not: none of the 9 lines pass between the first 2 points, like Python's `qqplot` with the 'q' option does.

How does the Python code calculate quantiles? [Looking at the source code](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/graphics/gofplots.html) we see that it uses the `mquantiles` function from scipy.stats.mstats. So we could compare the output from that with the R `quantile` function.

```
# Python
from scipy.stats.mstats import mquantiles
mquantiles(data_GPA['x'], prob=[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1])

array([2.06 , 2.447, 2.765, 3.159, 3.58 ])

# R
quantile(x, type = 7)

   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
2.060 2.465 2.765 3.045 3.580
```

We see that the values for the 0.25 and 0.75 quantile are different. This is also the case for the other 8 methods.

So what to conclude? The fitted lines are different because they use different methods to calculate quantiles. I don't know that we can say which one is "better" or "more reliable" - they're just different. Personally I think that the R `qqline` and the Python `qqplot` using the 'q' line are quite comparable, in that the last 3 points are furthest from the line in both cases.

Comment: Actually you can - see my answer. (Took way too much work to find it though.)

Comment: Great - yes, took me way too much work to get it not quite right :)